# Using Python to start shell but wont interrupt original script

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi

So I have a "master" python script which should be able to execute different shell scripts and not get stuck in the shell loops.

```
import socket
import subprocess
UDP_IP = "192.168.50.3"
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while (True):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)
    if (data == b'Hello, World!'):
       subprocess.call(['sh', './test.sh'])
    if (data == b'Hello, Bozo!'):
        subprocess.call(['sh', './test1.sh'])
```

^^The master script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo pkill -9 -f led
cd /home/maxi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/utils
 make led-image-viewer
 sudo ./led-image-viewer -C tenor.gif --led-rows=64 --led-cols=64 --led- 
 slowdown-gpio=2
```

^^The slave script (they all are looking almoast the same.)

I tried with 2 master scripts but I only want to have 1 udp connection so its not great. I didnt find much in the internet, probably because I cant really explain what I need?
My idea is to run different gifs on a led matrix and to switch I just kill the led process and restart it. (On a raspberry pi 3b+)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used subprocess.call. But if you take subprocess.probe it works without a problem.